# Black Hole and Mach Principle

Tags: black-holes, machs-principle

In the derivation of the spin–orbit interaction, we transform to a frame that is fixed on the electron. I have several questions about this:

1. Will I see any radiation if I orbit around a static charge?
2. Will I see a Kerr black hole if I orbit around a Schwarzchild black hole?
3. If I orbit around a Kerr black hole with the opposite direction of its angular momentum, will I see the black hole revolves around me without rotation? Is this a Schwarzchild black hole?

This is the Kerr metric
[image: Kerr metric]

By the coordinate transformation $\phi^{'}=\phi+\Omega t$
[image]

I'll get 
[image]
This isn't Schwarzchild metric

Comment: no if you orbit a Schwarzschild black hole you don't get a Kerr black hole, and also not a Schwarzschild black hole if you retrogradely orbit Kerr. Rotation and acceleration is not relative, in contrast to translatory motions.

Comment: So if I orbit around a Schwarzchild black hole, I still see a Schwarzchild black hole, it just changes another metric under my rotating reference frame.
And for I retrograde orbit Kerr, I will see a black hole which is not rotating, but it’s still Kerr.

Comment: why would it not be rotating if you orbit retrogradely? then the relative velocity of the surface would be even higher than if you orbit progradely. if you want to know what an unfed Kerr black hole (without an accretion disk) looks if you orbit retrogradely see here: http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=533#aberration . also if you want to orbit the black hole with the same angular velocity as the black hole itself that might easily exceed the speed of light, since same angular velocity times a higher radius is an even higher local velocity.

Comment: Oh yes, I mean prograde. My question is that is it possible for me to see a Kerr black hole which doesn’t rotate? Suppose I throw an object with a very small angular momentum into a Schwarzchild black hole, it will become a Kerr black hole with a very small angular momentum, is it possible for me to catch up?

Comment: Is this picture correct? A spacecraft outside the ergosphere can accelerate to reach a tie with the frame-dragging effect, and an infinite far observer will see the spacecraft as if it seems to stop by the Kerr BH, but the people inside the spacecraft will feel a great acceleration. Another question is that does frame-dragging effect breaks Mach’s principle?

Comment: if you orbit retrogradely with the negative frame dragging velocity you would stand still in the frame of a far away observer, for example here: http://gif.yukterez.net/kerr.orbits/kerr-newman-orbit-11.html you have a photon orbiting retrogradely at a distance where the frame dragging is c, that does move locally but not in the far away observer's frame.